# SSRS Forms Authentication : Unable to Add web service reference of ReportExecution2005.asmx from visual studio 2010

Tags: forms, authentication, reporting-services

Forms Authentication for SSRS has been successfully configured on my development box and i can succesfully log on to Report Manager and Report Builder using my security framework's credentials.

Now I want to make a console app which will consume the SSRS web services. however i am unable to to add reference of ReportExecution2005.asmx in console app project .

I get the following error on visual studio

---

The document at the url http://servername/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx was not recognized as a known document type.

The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:

- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The root element of a W3C XML Schema should be  and its namespace

---

While trying to add reference , In fiddler i can see the following error as response:

---

## Server Error in '/ReportServer' Application.

```
        <h2> <i>Access is denied.</i> </h2></span>

        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

        <b> Description: </b>An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.

        <b> Error message 401.2.: </b>Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration. &nbsp;Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server. &nbsp;Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.<br><br>

        <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4952; ASP.NET Version:2.0.5
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to duplicate the problem in Visual Studio 2010 connecting to my dev server running SSRS 2005. However, when adding the reference, try clicking the Advance button. In the next screen, click the "Add Web Reference..." button at the bottom of the dialog box. Perhaps that method will work better for you.